# startRange.offset - object does not support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error, offset

Receiving an error when I run the code below. This worked last month, just seemed to stop working since I performed an update on Octobers data.

The script should grab data from Derek_Calc, which is a list of all logins on a daily basis to an application on the server. This data is then compressed to highlight how many people are logging in per hour on any given day.

The following line is used to set the date information for where the data will be added to the table and the dates for which to check in the DEREK_Calcs:

```
Set tempRange = target1.Range("B1706:B1736")

Sub PopulateConcurrency()  'for re-populating specific dates for the 'DEREK_Concurrency_Logins' sheet
                                'UPDATE THE DATE RANGE below!

    Dim thisBook As Workbook
    Dim target1 As Worksheet
    Dim target2 As Worksheet
    Dim dbSheetNames(1 To 2) As String
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim cell2 As Variant
    Dim searchDate As String
    Dim firstColDate As Boolean
    Dim userIdLoginCount As Long
    Dim startHour As String
    Dim endHour As String
    Dim startDateTime As Date
    Dim endDateTime As Date
    Dim startDateHour As Date
    Dim endDateHour As Date
    Dim hourCounter As Integer
    Dim startRange As Range
    Dim endRange As Range
    Dim tempString As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim userIds() As Long
    Dim uniqueIds As Collection, c
    Dim targCellRange As Range
    Dim tempRange As Range
    Dim tempRange2 As Range

        dbSheetNames(1) = "DEREK_Concurrency_Logins"
        dbSheetNames(2) = "DEREK_Calcs"

        Set thisBook = ThisWorkbook
        Set target1 = thisBook.Sheets(dbSheetNames(1))
        Set target2 = thisBook.Sheets(dbSheetNames(2))

        'prepare variables
        userIdLoginCount = 0
        hourCounter = 0

        'de-activate re-calculations for this sheet as these will be updated later
        target1.EnableCalculation = False
        target2.EnableCalculation = False

        'stop screen refreshing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set tempRange = target1.Range("B1706:B1736") 'UPDATE THE DATE RANGE FROM COLUMN B Of THE 'DEREK_Concurrency_Logins' sheet
        For Each cell In tempRange   'loop through each date in the DEREK_Concurrency_User_Logins sheet

            searchDate = cell.Value
            searchDate = Format(searchDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            firstColDate = True
            hourCounter = 0

            For hourCounter = 0 To 16  'loop to next hour time range

                'get start hour and end hour
                startHour = target1.Cells(2, (3 + hourCounter))
                startHour = Format(startHour, "hh:mm")
                endHour = target1.Cells(2, (4 + hourCounter))
                endHour = Format(endHour, "hh:mm")

                'prepare variables
                Erase userIds
                Set uniqueIds = Nothing
                Set uniqueIds = New Collection
                userIdLoginCount = 0
                counter = 0

                With target2

                    Set tempRange2 = target2.Range("DEREK_LoginDaily")
                        For Each cell2 In tempRange2  'loop through each cell2 In DEREK_LoginDaily

                            If (StrComp(searchDate, cell2.Value) = 0) Then 'check for date match

                                If firstColDate = False Then

                                Set startRange = cell2
                                Set endRange = cell2

                                'get start and end hours for the hour period
                                startDateTime = startRange.Offset(0, 7).Value
                                endDateTime = endRange.Offset(0, 8).Value

                                'get the login start and finish times
                                tempString = Day(startDateTime) & "/" & Month(startDateTime) & "/" & Year(startDateTime) & " " & Format(startHour, "hh:mm")
                                startDateHour = CDate(tempString)

                                tempString = Day(endDateTime) & "/" & Month(endDateTime) & "/" & Year(endDateTime) & " " & Format(endHour, "hh:mm")
                                endDateHour = CDate(tempString)

                                    If startDateTime <= startDateHour And endDateTime >= endDateHour Then

                                        Sheets(dbSheetNames(2)).Select
                                        startRange.Offset(0, 10).Select
                                        startRange.Offset(0, 10).Activate
                                        ReDim Preserve userIds(counter)

                                        If (startRange.Offset(0, 10).Length > 0) Then
                                            If startRange.Offset(0, 6).Value = 1 Then
                                            userIds(counter) = startRange.Offset(0, 10).Value
                                            End If
                                        End If

                                        counter = counter + 1 'increment counter

                                    End If 'end hour concurency check

                                Else 'if firstColDate is True

                                    startHour = target1.Cells(2, 2) 'code for 7am - 8am, set startHour to 07:00
                                    endHour = target1.Cells(2, 4) 'set endHour to 08:00

                                    Set startRange = cell2
                                    Set endRange = cell2

                                    'get start and end hours for the hour period
                                    startDateTime = startRange.Offset(0, 7).Value
                                    endDateTime = endRange.Offset(0, 8).Value

                                    'get the login start and finish times
                                    tempString = Day(startDateTime) & "/" & Month(startDateTime) & "/" & Year(startDateTime) & " " & Format(startHour, "hh:mm")
                                    startDateHour = CDate(tempString)

                                    tempString = Day(endDateTime) & "/" & Month(endDateTime) & "/" & Year(endDateTime) & " " & Format(endHour, "hh:mm")
                                    endDateHour = CDate(tempString)

                                    If startDateTime <= startDateHour And endDateTime >= endDateHour Then

                                        Sheets(dbSheetNames(2)).Select
'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS :-(
                                        startRange.Offset(0, 10).Select
                                        startRange.Offset(0, 10).Activate
                                        ReDim Preserve userIds(counter)

                                        If (startRange.Offset(0, 10).Length > 0) Then
                                            If startRange.Offset(0, 6).Value = 1 Then
                                                userIds(counter) = startRange.Offset(0, 10).Value
                                            End If
                                        End If

                                        counter = counter + 1 'increment counter

                                    End If 'end hour concurency check
                                End If 'end if firstColDate
                            End If 'end if a date match

                        Next cell2 'loop through each cell2 In DEREK_LoginDaily

                    End With

                    'get unique values by putting array into a collection
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For Each c In userIds
                        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
                            uniqueIds.Add Item:=c, Key:=CStr(c)
                        End If
                    Next c

                    'populate target cell
                    Set targCellRange = cell
                    targCellRange.Offset(0, (2 + hourCounter)) = (uniqueIds.count)

                    firstColDate = False

                Next hourCounter 'loop to next hour time range

                firstColDate = True

            Next cell 'loop through each date in the DEREK_Concurrency_User_Logins sheet

            MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of cell2 at the moment of the error? Guessing the problem lies there. Run using step-in to see what it gives.

Comment: Have you checked what startrange is?  look at the `.address` and `.worksheet` properties of it, it could be the range definition or the range is in another worksheet perhaps.

Comment: ?cell2.value
03/02/2014

When I step through using F8, the value will update itself, starts off on 02/02/2014 and works through one line at a time through the spreadsheet.  It scrolls through 148000 lines before it gets to the right date.  But it does do it.

When I run the script and get the error:

?cell2.value
01/10/2018

Comment: ?startrange.Worksheet throws up the error message.

?startrange.address
$A$143857

Comment: @Lambik The results are shown above.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav The results are shown above.

Comment: Too much code. Can you trim this down to a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how, but this line is where the issue is:

startRange.Offset(0, 10).Length > 0

For a Range option you cannot have a length.  I received some help and changed the line to this:

Len(startRange.Offset(0, 10).Value)

This is now populating correctly.  The entire scripts job is to take a worksheet of data including login dates and times, and then populate another table detailing how many users were in the system on an hourly basis.

Thank you for the help everyone!